# Difference between InetAddresses's isInetAddress and isUriInetAddress

Tags: java, ip, uri, guava

Guava's `InetAddresses` utility class has two methods: `isInetAddress()`, `isUriInetAddress()`. What is the difference between a URI IP and a plain IP?

I assume `InetAddresses`'s methods are equally valid for IPv4 and IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isInetAddress` seems to just check the address for IPv4 or IPv6, i.e. the plain address.

`isUriInetAddress`  on the other hand tries to call `forUriString` and returns `true` if that succeeds.

The docs of `forUriString` state the following:

> Returns an InetAddress representing the literal IPv4 or IPv6 host portion of a URL, encoded in the format specified by RFC 3986 section 3.2.2.

Said section states the following:

- IPv4: `IPv4address`, e.g. `0.0.0.0`
- IPv6: `"[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"`

Thus for IPv4 both methods seem to have the same result while for IPv6 `isUriInetAddress` expects the address to be surrounded by square brackets.

Quick test:

```
//IPv4 are treated the same way
isInetAddress("0.0.0.0")      -> true
isUriInetAddress("0.0.0.0")   -> true

isInetAddress("[0.0.0.0]")    -> false
isUriInetAddress("[0.0.0.0]") -> false

//IPv6 are treated differently
isInetAddress("aaaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee")    -> true
isUriInetAddress("aaaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee") -> false

isInetAddress("[aaaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee]")    -> false
isUriInetAddress("[aaaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee]") -> true
```